# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on a dense set proof

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I wonder if the following statement is true and the proof is right:

[Statement]
Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set and $\overline{int(X)} = X$.
Given $\epsilon > 0 $, if there exists a function $g_{\epsilon}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$f(x) \leq g_{\epsilon}(x) \leq f(x) + h(\epsilon), \forall x \in int(X)$ where $h(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0+$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$ holds true for a continuous function $f$, then $g_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X$.

[Proof]
Since $f(x) \leq g_{\epsilon}(x) \leq f(x) + h(\epsilon), \forall x \in int(X)$, $g_{\epsilon}$ convergence pointwise to $f$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$. Further, $f$ is continuous.
By the second theorem of Ascoli (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3995213/711836)), $g_{\epsilon}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\overline{int(X)} = X$.

EDIT: $g_{\epsilon}$ is continuous.

Comment: Does $h$ depend on $x$?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Do you want the $g_\epsilon$s to be continuous?  Without this, you have no control at all over $g_\epsilon(x)$ for $x \notin int(X)$.  With this, everything is easy because $|f(x) - g_\epsilon(x)|$ is a continuous function which is bounded by $h(\epsilon)$ on a dense subset of $X$, and thus on all of $X$, so you immediately have uniform convergence.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the continuity condition of $g_{\epsilon}$. I see. So with the continuity condition, it's true, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.